# Package 'packageId' was restored using 'TargetFrameworkA' instead the project target framework 'TargetFrameworkB'

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, asp.net-core-3.1, nuget-package-restore

I am getting following warnings when I build Web API project B which targets .netCore 3.1 on local.

[image]

The Packages named in warnings are referenced within Project A (source) which also targets .netcore 3.1.

The nuget package of project A is created and is referenced in project B.
But when I build project B I get warnings mentioned in the image.

> I have tried updating the packages in Project A and then referenced
> again in Project B as a nuget package but still the same issue.

Comment: your target project .netcoreapp whereas nugget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core is supported by only .NET Framework https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: Due do this warning are you getting are runtime error or anything?

Comment: Thanks Laxmikant . Yeah that is due to attribute implementation in the source project.
@MdFaridUddinKiron No not any errors as such.

Comment: Are you getting your refereences on your code? Is thats working as expected?

Comment: Yes we have created nuget package and referencing it in another project where i see warnings

Comment: If all features functioning well you could ignore these warnings.